# (android-layout) GridView with Image and Text adds extraspace around Image

Tags: android-layout

I want a Gridview with Images and corresponding Text over them. It nearly does work, but there is some extraspace around my images. I first thought the space would be below textview und the imageview, but when removing the text, same space has been there. I read that I would have to add android:adjustViewBounds="true" to my imageview to remove this extraspace, but than my App crashes. Can anyone help me? When does a layout in general crash?

Here is the xml of the griditems

single_grid_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
  android:id = "@+id/single_item_id"          
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"             
  android:orientation="vertical"
  > 
      <TextView
      android:id = "@+id/image_name"
      android:layout_width = "fill_parent"             
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
      <ImageView
      android:id = "@+id/album_image"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:layout_width = "fill_parent"             
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

 </LinearLayout>
```

This is the XML for the complete Sreenlayout.

home_1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <LinearLayout             
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"             
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"             
  android:orientation="vertical">   
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/home_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
        android:background="#231f20" 
        android:focusable = "true"
    >

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1searchButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:background = "@drawable/magnify"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />
    <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1loadButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/adjustmt"
   android:focusable = "true"

   />
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1editButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/assist"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1sendButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/radio"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1folderupButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/folderup"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />
    <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1newfoldrButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/newfoldr"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />
    <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1trashButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/trash"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />
    <Button
   android:id="@+id/home1yesButton"
   android:text=""
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/yes"
   android:focusable = "true"
   />


</LinearLayout>
```

For filling the Gridview, I use my ImageAdapter, which extends baseadapter. This is its getVIew Function:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ImageView icon;
        icon = new ImageView(mContext);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)             mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_griditem, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
        label.setText(fileNameArray.get(position));
        icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.album_image);

        icon.setImageBitmap(bmArray.get(position));

        return row;
    }
```

And this is my onCreate-Function

```
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_1);

        String [] a = null;

        ImageAdapter mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        Bitmap mBitmap = null; 


        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a1 + i );
            ImageAdapter.addImage(mBitmap, "sample_"+1+".jpg");
        }


        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.home_1);
        gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(gridview);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem: [ViewFlipper not wrapping around images correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158446/viewflipper-not-wrapping-around-images-correctly/7158739#7158739) *android:adjustViewBounds="true"* worked for me.
Try using *setAdjustViewBounds(true)* instead of setting it up in the XML. If the image source is not ready while doing the layout, the ImageView will have no bounds to adjust to, so the app could crash.