# ViewFlipper not wrapping around images correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some ImageViews inside a ViewFlipper. I want to **respect the aspect ratio** of the images, so the layout won't use all the screen. I have set up a simple "slide" animation, but the ViewFlipper will always be a bit bigger than the images inside. This makes an **undesired black space** appear between two sliding images. I can't make the ViewFlipper wrap around the ImageViews correctly.

Everything is inside a FrameLayout, so there I can have a floating button there too. This is the main layout XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    > 
 <ViewFlipper
     android:id="@+id/flipper"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"   
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     >
  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/page1"   
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      android:src="@drawable/bg0"
      />
  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/page2"   
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      android:src="@drawable/bg1"
      />   
 </ViewFlipper>
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/menuButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:src="@drawable/btn_menu"
  android:background="@null"
  />    
</FrameLayout>
```

If I set the scaleType of the ImageViews to "fitXY" the black margin disappears, but the ratio of the images is not respected. I have already tried "fitCenter", "fillParent" in the ImageViews, and a padding of 0px.

Any help is very much appreciated as I have been struggling with this for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to the ImageView did it:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: The solution was in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212037/android-layout-gridview-with-image-and-text-adds-extraspace-around-image